# Prevent urxvt window from closing when a child process is running

Tags: perl, rxvt

Sometimes when working within a terminal, e.g. when using Vim, I accidentally close the window without saving my work properly.

`gnome-terminal` will show a dialog before closing a terminal window that has a subprocess running besides the shell. 
I'd like to have a similar feature with `urxvt`; it would be enough if the window simply refuses to close whenever there are subprocesses running.

Is there a setting (or maybe a Perl plugin) addressing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same desire as you did, so I built an extension myself. I am not very experienced in writing Perl code, but it's quite straightforward. We check whether there are child processes associated with the shell running in the terminal. If so the bell is rung and the event consumed. Be aware the urxvt's behaviour for ringing the bell is dependent on further configurations.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub on_wm_delete_window {
    my ($self, $event) = @_;
    my $CP = `ps --ppid $self->{shell_pid} -o pid= | wc -l`;
    chomp $CP;
    if ( $CP != 0 ) {
        $self->scr_bell;
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

sub on_child_start {
    my($self, $pid) = @_;
    $self->{shell_pid} = $pid;
}
```

*Adapting the answer of user1986653:*

Simply place the scripts you want to install in `/usr/lib/urxvt/perl/` for system-wide availability or in `~/.urxvt/ext/` for user-only availability. Let's call the file `close-gracefully` and modify your `~/.Xresources` or `~/.Xdefaults`

```
URxvt.perl-ext-common: ...,close-gracefully
```

Don't forget to run `xrdb ~/[filename]` after each file modification. For a discussion of the difference between `~/.Xresources` and `~/.Xdefaults` see this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/243914/xresources-or-xdefaults).

Comment: Just for completeness, please explain how this would be used. Do not respond in comments; [edit] your post to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @Scott, done that by simply adapting the other answer! Hope, this is the correct way to disclose this. If not, let me know how to correct! Thanks from a newbie!

Comment: Beautiful! This works exactly as I wanted it to. Closes the shell on Alt+F4, but not while any process is running inside it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using tabbed extension, thus the solution is simple - comment out the line destroying the tabs in the routine on_wm_delete_window [see this](https://urxvt.wordpress.com/tag/urxvt-rxvt-unicode/).

If you don't use the tabbed extension (I cannot imagine ;-)), you can use the script from Floyd's answer. The simplest form of the script is

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl  
sub on_wm_delete_window {
    return 1;
}
```

Simply place the scripts you want to install in `/usr/lib/urxvt/perl/` for system-wide availability or in `~/.urxvt/ext/` for user-only availability. Let's call the file `close-prevent` and modify your `~/.Xdefaults`

```
URxvt.perl-ext-common: ...,close-prevent
```

Don't forget to run `xrdb ~/.Xdefaults` after each file modification.

The uxrvt terminal window is not possible to close by Alt-F4 or by close button. `exit` command / Ctrl-D still works.

Comment: This is probably better if you do something like `urxvt -e vim` and don't want to lose the vim session to Alt+F4.